# How to restrict the User to put more than two decimal points on the Edit Text

Tags: android

We have Edittext which can take Decimal value. So I have used

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:numeric="decimal"
```

Now EditText takes decimal values. My Query is can I control the user to enter only upto two decimal places?

For example `1345.99`, he cannot put more than two digit after decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there can be two solution,

1) let user not allow after he entered something like this xxx.xx.

2) let him enter it and when saving the value or taking an action on the screen, Check the value of edittext and generate a toast if the value entered is not in the desired format.

for second solution here you go. /

```
    String str = editText.getText().toString();

    int indexOFdec =  str.indexOf(".");

    if(indexOFdec >=0) {
       if(str.substring(indexOFdec).length() >2)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Print a message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return;
       }
    }
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks For your answer. I will use one of the above method as per our requirement.

Comment: ya this should be work but i want user dont enter any numeric value after he/she enter something like xxx.xx 
 means i want disable the numeric keyboard or anything else wtever

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure if you can do this in XML, a good workaround would be to just make a substring of the EditText after calling getText.toString() and extract the necessary tokens. Just look for the decimal character "." in the String and extract the 2 indexes after it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on another website, but SO won't let me link, saying that this content is not allowed in an answer.

This implementation of `InputFilter` solves the problem:

```
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;

public class MoneyValueFilter extends DigitsKeyListener {
public MoneyValueFilter() {
    super(false, true);
}

private int digits = 2;

public void setDigits(int d) {
    digits = d;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    CharSequence out = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);

    // if changed, replace the source
    if (out != null) {
        source = out;
        start = 0;
        end = out.length();
    }

    int len = end - start;

    // if deleting, source is empty
    // and deleting can't break anything
    if (len == 0) {
        return source;
    }

    int dlen = dest.length();

    // Find the position of the decimal .
    for (int i = 0; i < dstart; i++) {
        if (dest.charAt(i) == '.') {
            // being here means, that a number has
            // been inserted after the dot
            // check if the amount of digits is right
            return (dlen-(i+1) + len > digits) ? 
                "" :
                new SpannableStringBuilder(source, start, end);
        }
    }

    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        if (source.charAt(i) == '.') {
            // being here means, dot has been inserted
            // check if the amount of digits is right
            if ((dlen-dend) + (end-(i + 1)) > digits)
                return "";
            else
                break;  // return new SpannableStringBuilder(source, start, end);
        }
    }

    // if the dot is after the inserted part,
    // nothing can break
    return new SpannableStringBuilder(source, start, end);
}
}
```

Comment: It is from efreedom and is answered by user name Konstantin Weitz; I am very sorry but I cannot link you because I cannot figure out why it won't let me put a link in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher` to check how many points does your EditText contains. In case the number of points is more then one edit text of EditText.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// Logic to check how many points does contain your EditText
}

});
```